# Detect type of an ode

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have been trying to detect the type of the following ode in order to solve it (trying with homogenous, exact, bernoulli, riccati etc) but I haven't been able to find it:
$y^2dx=(x^2-1+y^2x^2-y^2)dy$.
Could anyone give me any advice? Thanks.

Comment: It is separable, you can factorize the right side easily.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $y^{2}\, {\rm d}x=(x^{2}-1+y^{2}x^{2}-y^{2})\, {\rm d}y$ can be written as $$\frac{1}{x^{2}-1}\,{\rm d}x=\frac{y^{2}+1}{y^{2}}\, {\rm d}y,\quad $$ since $x^{2}-1+y^{2}x^{2}-y^{2}=(x^{2}-1)(y^{2}+1)$. So the ODE is separable and you can solve it by integration to both sides.